# Is possible to refresh index.html in angular app without reload page?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I have angular app (php+mysql) with 4 views. Is It possible refresh index.html when I click button in view (button who write data to database) ?

Comment: yes, It's possible.

Comment: How to do this ?

Comment: Yes please it is possible... please refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893497/how-to-call-http-request-on-ng-click-event)

You have make one api for write data to db in php

Comment: what do you mean by refresh . `update the data` or render the `index html again`

Comment: Data is updated in mysql, but I must reload index to see the result (notifycation who read from database in ng-repeat)

Comment: You have to call once again api which used for ng-repeat after successfully updated the data.

Comment: When I add function o.getO($scope.o) return error: callback is not a function.